# Update query not working

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I have an update query that shouldbe working but for some reason it doesnt work

```
String sql="UPDATE TB_EARTHORIENTATIONPARAMETER_UI SET  YEAR='year1',  MONTH='month1',  DAY='day1',  MJD='mjd1',  WHERE (EOPID=1)";
```

It gives me the following error

```
Incorrect integer value 'year1' for column YEAR at row1
```

my table consist of the following columns and their types

```
| EOPID         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| YEAR          | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| MONTH         | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DAY           | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| MJD           | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

I retrieve the valuues to use in my sql update query from a jTable in the following manner

```
Object year=model.getValueAt(row, column);
        years=year.toString();
        year1=Integer.parseInt(years);
```

so i believe i am using the correct type but i cant figure out why it wont update . Is this a mysql version thing?

Comment: You haven't shown us any code that substitutes the value for `year1` into the query string...

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually passing the value of year1 (or any of them, for that matter) into the sql query string, just the name of the variable.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I suspect that's because there isn't any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like.

```
String sql="UPDATE TB_EARTHORIENTATIONPARAMETER_UI 
            SET  
                YEAR="+year1+",  
                MONTH="+month1+",  
                DAY="+day1+",  
                MJD="+mjd1+"  
            WHERE 
                EOPID=1";
```

Where `year1`, `month1`, `day1`, `mjd1` should be variables containing appropriate values (there is an extra comm before the `WHERE` clause though).

Answer (score 0):

The system is complaining that you're giving it a STRING ("year1"), not the integer value (e.g. 2012) it's expecting.

You should write this more like:

```
String sql="UPDATE TB_EARTHORIENTATIONPARAMETER_UI SET  YEAR=" +
            year1.toString() + ", month..."
```